# Can not find/click this button with Selenium/Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, xpath

I am trying to press this "New Search" button. It appears on the top of the screen after entering a search on http://www.lexisnexis.com/hottopics/lnacademic/

I have looked at the Xpath and Unique Selector.

What I have tried:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#restoreButtons > a:nth-child(3)').click()
browser.find_element_by_xpath(id('restoreButtons')/x:a[3])
browser.find_element_by_xpath(/x:a[3])
```

For all three I get an "unable to locate element error"

Comment: You can go with `//a[text()='New Search']`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the element is *inside an `iframe`.* You have to be in the context to search elements inside. Use `.switch_to.frame()`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "mainFrame")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
```

FYI, here is the complete working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.lexisnexis.com/hottopics/lnacademic/')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "mainFrame")))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

driver.find_element_by_id("terms").send_keys("Test")
driver.find_element_by_id("srchButt").click()
```

Comment: I tried that and got an error saying it is unable to locate the frame

Comment: Is this working for you? because I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm looking to press the "new search" button AFTER submitting a search

Answer (score 0):

To build on alecxes answer,

once you're inside the iframe, you can find the clickable using it's xpath:

```
new_search_xpath = '/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/span/a[3]'
new_search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, new_search_xpath)
new_search.click()
```

You should consider installing firebug firefox addon to grab Xpaths:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Comment: I'm still getting a timeoutexception :/